# How to make TypeScript infer type of property using template literal type

Tags: typescript

I asked similar question few months ago (it did get desired answer), this time its a bit different, and more specific.
I thought that it is straight forward in TypeScript, but seems it is not.

```
function retObj<T extends string>(suff: T, n: number): {[k in `fixed${T}`]: number} {
  const k: `fixed${T}` = `fixed${suff}`; 
  const r: {[k in `fixed${T}`]: number} = {[k]: n * 2};
  return r;
}
```

It doesn't compile  because `{[k]: n * 2}` can not be assigned to r which is of type `` {[k in `fixed${T}`]: number} ``.
If I write that line like this, it works: `` const r = {[k]: n * 2} as {[k in `fixed${T}`]: number}; ``

How can I specify return type of the function and not use casting (`as`) inside the function, but rather let compiler infer correct type and actually tell me if I've implemented the function correctly and it indeed returns specified type?

Explanation of how type system actually works, and why it work like that, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is multiple questions in one post and therefore not focused enough; please [edit] to ask a single well-defined question, or identify one of those as the primary question, so we can answer it or point to a relevant duplicate. If you need to ask three different questions you should make three different posts.

Comment: @jcalz OK, but they are related, and I thought that the answer would be more complete if I ask all three.

Comment: Unfortunately computed keys whose type isn't a specific string literal (yours is generic) are currently widened to `string`, resulting in a string index signature. This is a bug as per [ms/TS#13948](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) but I don't know when/if it';ll be addressed (it's been open for a while). For now you pretty much need to use a type assertion (what you call "casting"), and if you're only doing it once you might as well do it inline the way you're doing. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll answer or point to an existing q/a. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Great answer, you should write it as an answer.

Comment: Please see the linked questions and their answers for more information.

Comment: @jcalz OK, thanks. I will not delete question, maybe it will be easier for some people to find this duplicate rather than original, as I also failed to find these original questions.